# C# Object Intantiation format question declaring a variable vs not declaring a variable

Tags: c#, object, instance, new-operator, instantiation

I am new to C# and I think I am seeing 2 diferent ways to do the same thing or maybe I just am not understanding. My "Murach's C# 2015" book has on page 369 an example of creating 2 object instances like this:

```
Product product1, product2;
product1 = new Product("something", "something else", more stuff);
product2 = new Product("something different", "something else different", more different stuff);
```

Can you also do it this way?

```
Product product1 = new Product("something", "something else", more stuff);
Product product2 = new Product("something different", "something else different", more different stuff);
```

It seems like some sources online do it one way and other sources do it the other way, or like I said... Maybe I am just missing something.

Comment: Both styles are correct. The second style is encouraged (see [Why declare variables close to where they are used?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113262/why-declare-variables-close-to-where-they-are-used)). The first style can be used when it is not possible to declare the variable at the same time it is initialized, e.g. if it must be declared outside a `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variable (once) before you use it, but you can assign the declared  object variable multiple times.

```
// declare the variable
Product product1 
// assign to first product
product1 = new Product("first product");
// assign to a different product
product1 = new Product("second product");
```

You can use the technique of declaring and assigning as "shorthand", so you could combine the first two lines of code (not counting the comments):

```
//declare and assign the variable in one step
Product product1 = new Product("first product");
//re-assign the previously declared variable to a different object
product1 = new Product("second product");
```

You only declare the variable once so this would give you an error:

```
Product product1 = new Product("first product");
Product product1 = new Product("second product");
```

Answer (score 1):

**First Part**

First style is preferred when you need to access your variable outside the scope lets say
if you need to only instantiate your object inside an if condition and you also need to access object outside if condition then you would be doing it like this

```
Product product1;

if(condition == true)
{
    product1 = new Product("something", "something else", more stuff);
}

product1.isInitiated = true
```

Here only first type of initialization will work because we need to access it outside if condition

**Second Part**

Now if you only required to access property inside if loop then second method will also work lets say

```
if(condition == true)
{
    Product product1 = new Product("something", "something else", more stuff);
    product1.isInitiated = true 
}
```

In this case you have a choice either to instantiate and initialize at the same point or do it inside if loop